# Syntax error in sqlite trying to create a database

Tags: sqlite

I am new to SQLite. I downloaded the latest version of SQLite (both shell and dll) and extract them to my `D:` drive. I execute the 'sqlite3.exe' file by double clicking on that.

When I try to create the database with the command `sqlite3 test.db;`, I get this error.

> D:\Android Work\Sqlite\sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3070800>sqlite3.exe
>   SQLite version 3.7.8 2011-09-19 14:49:19
>   Enter ".help" for instructions
>   Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
>   sqlite> sqlite3 test.db
>   ...> ;
>   Error: near "sqlite3": syntax error
>   sqlite>

Please help me..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you have to type "sqlite3 test.db" from the command line prompt, not from inside the interactive SQLite interface.

See [here](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html):

```
 $ sqlite3 test.db
 SQLite version 3.0.8
 Enter ".help" for instructions
 sqlite> .quit
 $
```

Comment: You can also use the ATTACH DATABASE command to create a new database from within the sqlite shell, but providing it at the command line like this is the best, "cleanest" option.

Answer (score 3):

If you're seeing `sqlite>` then you are inside SQLite. You need to come out with `.quit` and then type `sqlite3 testDB.db` to create a database file managed with SQLite

Example below:

```
sqlite> sqlite3 testDB.db
...> CREATE TABLE first(a int, b string);
Error: near "sqlite3": syntax error
sqlite> .quit

C:\Users\>sqlite3 testDB.db
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .databases
main: C:\Users\testDB.db
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you type sqlite3 in the terminal or cmd you're getting into SQLite command prompt which doesn't allow you to create DB

[image]

so quit from cmd or terminal using this command .quit

[image]

now run the following command to create a new DB "sqlite3 siya.db" where "siya" is the database name and check created database using the following command .databases(to check all the databases)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

open cmd and type cd\ and then
C:>cd sqlite
C:\sqlite>sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.39.2 2022-07-21 15:24:47
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .databases
main: C:\sqlite\test.db r/w
sqlite>